# How to implement word embedding on dataset which have numerical as well as text data

Tags: python, machine-learning, word-embedding

I am working on word embedding for recommendation but i am able to convert the text to vectors but don't have any idea about the how to deal with numeric data.

```
product_pid review_id   customer_id customer_nickname   customer_location   customer_age    customer_gender customer_skin   customer_eyes   submission_time product_rating  review_title    review_text adore   bon eau aime    odeur   toilette    sent    super   belle   agréable    parfait meilleur    produit parfumparfum    senteur sublime tenue   vrai    parfumun    envoûtant   cadeau  fragrance   adoreparfum préféré adoreun excellent   nouveau merveille   coeur   pure    sensuel bonheur envoutant   doux    coffret classique   mal love    léger   découverte  pur classe  must    déçue   unique  superbe nuit    divinement  adoreune    tiens   saint   fraîcheur   air best    adoremon    grande  bonj    sucré   adoresuper  intense robe    original    valeur  interdit    surprise    sauvage floral  adooore délice  parfumeau   merveilleux nouvelle    lasse   longue  subtil  qualité véritable   fleuri  printemps   gourmand    élégance    caractère   incontournable  fruité  plaisir miss    amour   satisfaite  chic    fort    douceur rapport cher    dommage sens    divin   absolument  déception   délicieux   déçu
P3751006    129824090   70837926    clementine21    Paris   25to34  Female  Seche   Marrons 2019-06-21T15:25:43.000+00:00   5   Mon coup de coeur de l'été  Pas grande amatrice de vanille d'habitude, j'ai eu un réel coup de coeur pour vanilla ! 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
P3751006    129287039   71723071    sarakil paris   18to24  Female  Grasse  Marrons 2019-06-05T10:25:11.000+00:00   5   Le parfum parfait pour l'été !  j'adore le mix entre l'odeur de la mer et l'odeur de la vanille. Je ne suis pas forcément fan de la Vanille mais dans ce parfum, elle est irrésistible !!   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
P3751006    129235729   73117641    Cécile b    ASNIERES    35to44  Female  Seche   Bleus   2019-06-03T17:46:31.000+00:00   5   Sublime ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️  J’adore cette touche de sel dans cette douceur de vanille , je suis tomber amoureuse de ce parfum, le parfum de l’ete Qui va faire carton ...   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
P22409  125469274   74968022    ERIC 93150  LE BLANC MESNIL plus54  Male    Seche   Verts   2019-03-14T15:43:06.000+00:00   5   MUGLER  EXCELLENT tout simplement !! Ma fille toujours fidèle à ANGEL   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
P22409  124974886   75427663        La Crau 45to54  Female  Grasse  Marrons 2019-03-01T16:18:08.000+00:00   5   Une madeleine de Proust Un parfum qui me rappelle des souvenirs, la fragrance n'a pas changée, telle que je l'ai sentie la première fois, il y a quelques années....une image, une période de vie, un été, ..... C'est tellement appréciable d'avoir de nouveau ces mêmes senteurs, inchangées, SI les créateurs pouvaient lire ce message, je les féliciterai et les remercierai, vraiment.    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the embeddings?

Comment: @chefhose This project is about perfumes. all perfumes are composed from smells called "notes" and other chimical ingredients. But the most important information in any perfume is the notes used to design it.

Comment: @chefhose We have data about some perfumes: id, price, name, brand, notes ( all the notes), ingredients I have also data about customers: Id customer, age, gender, the perfumes they used and their IDs, reviews , rating, live counts, popularity .. After a data processing step 1- we will apply words embeddings on both tables using gloves and word2vec 2-build a deep learning algorithm feeded by the embeddings For any costumer the idea is to predict the best notes ( or perfumes ).